# C++ Exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and PcapPlusPlus.I want my app to print a certain header(for example user-agent) of http packets and then drop packages that have a certain value(but I didn't reach the dropping part yet).When I compile my code it works fine but when I make a request to some site it prints for example "user-agent whatever" and then throws an exception at me: read access violation.
**this* was 0x58. I'm a total newbie to c++ and visual studio so I have no idea what does that exception mean.How do I fix this?Here's my code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "PcapLiveDeviceList.h"
#include "PlatformSpecificUtils.h"
#include "Packet.h"
#include "TcpLayer.h"
#include "HttpLayer.h"
     struct PacketStats
     {
     void consumePacket(pcpp::Packet& packet)
     {
     pcpp::HttpRequestLayer* httpRequestLayer = packet.getLayerOfType<pcpp::HttpRequestLayer>();
    if (packet.isPacketOfType(pcpp::HTTP)) 
        printf("HTTP,%s\n",httpRequestLayer->getFieldByName(PCPP_HTTP_USER_AGENT_FIELD)->getFieldValue().c_str());
}
};
static void onPacketArrives(pcpp::RawPacket* packet, pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* dev, void* cookie)
{
PacketStats* stats = (PacketStats*)cookie;
pcpp::Packet parsedPacket(packet);
stats->consumePacket(parsedPacket);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::string interfaceIPAddr = "192.168.0.249";
pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* dev = pcpp::PcapLiveDeviceList::getInstance().getPcapLiveDeviceByIp(interfaceIPAddr.c_str());
if (dev == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot find interface with IPv4 address of '%s'\n", interfaceIPAddr.c_str());
    exit(1);
}
if (!dev->open())
{
    printf("Cannot open device\n");
    exit(1);
}
PacketStats stats;
pcpp::PortFilter portFilter(80, pcpp::SRC_OR_DST);
pcpp::ProtoFilter protocolFilter(pcpp::TCP);
pcpp::AndFilter andFilter;
andFilter.addFilter(&portFilter);
andFilter.addFilter(&protocolFilter);
dev->setFilter(andFilter);
printf("\nStarting packet capture with a filter in place...\n");
dev->startCapture(onPacketArrives, &stats);
PCAP_SLEEP(10);
dev->stopCapture();
dev->close();
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: I'd like to recommend looking at [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) ...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with C++ in this capacity, but I have a few ideas. First, you're getting a "read access violation". I'd be thinking reading invalid memory. Second, it's telling you that the 'this' pointer is 0x58. That's a very low number, close to 0x0. It's likely that you are getting back a null pointer, and using it somewhere else.

Could it be that httpRequestLayer, or something else within your call chain in consumePacket is coming back null?